# Dispatch Redux action inside Chrome Extension Background Page with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, redux

I'm working on a background page in a Chrome extension that dispatches a Redux action asynchronously with Thunk.  The action creator is defined like the following:

```
export const executeProcess = (data: Data[]): ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction> => async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>): Promise<void> => {
```

I'm able to dispatch this perfectly fine from a screen using the component's map dispatch to props, that is:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    executeProcess: executeProcess,
};
```

And:

```
eventTest = async () => {

        //
        //  Kickoff process
        await this.props.executeProcess(this.props.data);
    };
```

And the JSX itself:

```
<button onClick={this.eventTest}>EVENT TESTER</button>
```

I'm trying to do something similar in the background page, notably:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(async () => {
await store.dispatch(executeProcess(store.getState().data))
});
```

And doing so invokes the following TS error:

```
Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

I'm using the webext-redux NPM package so that I'm able to work with the store in both the screens and background pages and am able to read from the store in the background page, however can't dispatch actions.  The dispatch definition requires an instance of type AnyAction, that is:

```
export interface AnyAction extends Action
```

However the ThunkAction naturally extends from Action:

```
export type ThunkAction<R, S, E, A extends Action> = (
```

Is there any way I can change the signature of the action creator so that the dispatch works without issues in both the screens and also the background page?

How I'm declaring my store.ts using the (aforementioned NPM) is the following:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
let store: Store<RootState>;

store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, loadState());
store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
    saveState(store.getState())
}, 1000));

wrapStore(store, {
    portName: constants.ApplicationName,
});

export {store};
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution/kludge to make this work, define the store like the following:

```
let store: Store<RootState, any>;
```

which resolves to the following:

```
export interface Store<S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction> {
```

instead of this:

```
let store: Store<RootState>;
```

Ideally would pass ThunkAction instead of any type, but ran into generic argument issue.